# RxJava prevent throwing error when calling doOnSuccess()

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

I've noticed that if an exception is thrown inside `doOnSuccess()` the subscriber will not receive `onSuccess()` but `onError()`. is there a way to prevent this behavior? I thought about surrounding everything with try-catch but it's clearly not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, do not crash in `doOnSuccess`. If the crash is ignorable in your business case, just try-catch it and don't let RxJava know about it.

Comment: @akarnokd Is there a reason exceptions in `doOnSuccess` are propagated instead of ignored? Just curious if this was a legacy decision or otherwise. I can see the motivation for not silently dropping errors, but we also ran into an unexpected pattern of using `doOnSuccess` more like a `changeToErrorIfException`-type of operator.

Comment: Yes; we don't ignore exceptions from user code. If we did, the flows would most likely hang and good luck figuring out why. It is a reliability consideration as well as user-control consideration. For example, if the user code would want to throw deliberately and we ignored it, there was no way to enable it with the operator.